# HTTPS connection

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

i am using the following code for establishing Https connection

```
    HttpsConnection httpConnector = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    Document doc ;
    String content = "";

            try 
                {
               httpConnector = (HttpsConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
                    httpConnector.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET) ;
                    in = httpConnector.openInputStream();
                    byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
                    int len = 0;
                    int size = 0;
                    StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
                        while ( -1 != (len = in.read(data)) ) {
                            raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                            size += len;
                        }
                        content = raw.toString().trim();
                                }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                       return false;  
                   }
                   try{
                    in.close();
                    in =null;
                    httpConnector.close();
                    httpConnector =null;

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Dialog.alert("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
                return false;

            } 
            }
```

i think i am able to establish the connection but the values are not coming. i am testing it on Simulator, i have not tested on device

Comment: I am able to fetch the value using httpconnection using the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is in the following line:

```
byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
```

The `available()` method only returns how many bytes are immediately available for reading from the inputstream, but you are using it to initialize the size of the temporary byte array.  Since it's possible that available() returns 0, you may be initializing a zero-length array.

It would be better to just initialize "data" with a fixed-length array.

Comment: It may just be a coincidence of timing that HTTP connections have a positive value for available() whereas HTTPS perhaps is returning 0.  It wouldn't hurt to try and just replace it with a fixed-length byte array.

Comment: i think there is no getLength() for inputstream

Comment: I replaced in.available() with some static value say 1024, still nothing is displayed.

Comment: A few followup questions: is this a self-signed SSL site or signed by a trusted CA such as Verisign?  Is it throwing any exceptions?  Can you try it on a real device?

Comment: i am able to see the value i have used 100000 as a static value 
but the problem i dont want to keep the static value, so wat's the alterntive reason for that

Comment: You can use a small value such as 1024 - it's only a temporary buffer to read bytes into from the inputstream.  If it's not big enough to hold your entire response body, it will just keep looping doing more reads (and adding data to your StringBuffer).  Once the JVM leaves that code block the byte array will no longer be references and thus can be garbage collected, so don't worry about it using up memory.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the IOUtilities class for an easier way to read an InputStream into a byte array without having to set up temporary buffers, loops, etc.